# pip giving error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enum'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Running python 3.7.7 on Windows 7 x64.  I've just upgraded from python 2.7 and I'm trying to install the module `emcee` using `pip install emcee`.  Pip threw the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enum'`.  I've also tried installing modules matplotlib, enum34, and numpy, but all threw the same error.  I've also tried to upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip` , which again threw the same error.  I've looked into my `\python37\lib` folder, and `enum.py` is present right where it's supposed to be, but it's still not working.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried with pip3 ?

Comment: Also, try `pip freeze` and `pip3 freeze` to list all available packages. Since you upgraded from Py2 to Py3, there is a chance you are referring to Py2 when typing pip install, not pip3 install

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm that you have python installed ie it’s upgraded and in existence. You can do this by typing python in the cmd or terminal window. This should push you into a python shell. If it does not do so. Trying reinstalling python. May be the upgrade did not work so well.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is part of the standard library for Python 3.7, and you've confirmed that it's there. Therefore the error raises the suspicion that, when you're launching `pip`, it might be getting executed by a Python distribution/installation *other than* the one you think it is. One way to make sure it's working on the correct distro is to say:

```
C:\WHATEVER\PATH\TO\python.exe -m pip install emcee
```

This is more precise than just typing `pip` at the command-line, because in the latter case you just have to hope/assume that the first `pip` Windows finds on its `%Path%` will be the correct one. That's not always the case.